# ERROR IN SQL QUERY for group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to select average salary by department number and age, I used this query

```
SELECT 
    DEPARTMENT_NUMBER,
    ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, BIRTHDAY)) / 12) AS AGE,
    AVG(SALARY)
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY 
    DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, AGE;
```

but I am getting error:

> ORA-00904: "AGE": invalid identifier

Comment: Tagged Oracle . . . Oracle errors come from the Oracle database.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a column alias in the `group by` in Oracle.  Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, AGE, AVG(SALARY)
FROM (SELECT e.*, ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,BIRTHDAY))/12) AS AGE
      FROM EMPLOYEE
     ) e
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, AGE;
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot group by an alias, try this:

```
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_NUMBER
           ,ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,BIRTHDAY))/12) AS AGE
           ,AVG(SALARY)
    FROM EMPLOYEE 
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,BIRTHDAY))/12);
```